# Chrome Extension: Print all cookies in background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm reading the docs for google Chrome and want to print out a list of all of the cookies

backgroundScript.js

```
console.log('this ran')
chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function (cookies) {
    cookies.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item)
    })
});
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage"
],
```

However its returning an empty string.

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How do I print out a list of all of the cookies?

I checked in chrome settings and see the cookies present.

Is it a permissions thing? I feel like I'm not using the `cookies` response correctly, but unsure how to debug it.

Comment: Your permissions allow only one site. To read cookies for all sites, add `"<all_urls>"`.

Comment: I see...thank you! that worked